# PHP consumir Web service con datos de tipo arrayofObjeto

Tags: php, webservice, soap

Quiero consumir un web service desde php conformado de esta manera:

```html
<s:element name="Metodo">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Encabezado" type="tns:EncabezadoInicio" />
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Lineas" type="tns:ArrayOfLinea" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:complexType name="EncabezadoInicio">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Nombre" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Direccion" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Numero" type="s:string" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="ArrayOfLinea">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Linea" nillable="true" type="tns:Linea" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="Linea">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="codigo" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Cantidad" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Descripcion" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Precio" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Descuento" type="s:string" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
```

Como puedo consumir este web service? pues los datos enviados son de otro tipo de objetos que no son string, alguna idea?

Ahora lo que tengo solo es un objeto, cuyos indices tiene

```js
      $Encabezado['Nombre']               = 'Su nombre';
      $Encabezado['Direccion']              = 'su direccion';
      $Encabezado['Numero']              = 'su numero';
      
  // como envio las lineas?
```

Comment: Depende mucho la documentación del web service que estés tratando de consumir, ¿estás usando algún frame work back-end?

Comment: Ya lo he resuelto! Gracias, pero olvide poner la respuesta, ya la pongo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya la he resuelto.
El web service permite enviar mas lineas de un mismo tipo, asi que lo que hice fue un contador

```js
public function obtener_ArrayLineas($dato){
  $array_lineas= metodo_obtener_detalle($dato);
  $ArrayOfLineas= [];
  //ese metodo devuelve un objeto con el detalle del documento

  foreach($array_lineas as $key=>$detalle){
    $ArrayOfLineas['Linea'][] = $detalle;
  }
  
  return $ArrayOfLineas;
}
```

Entonces cuando mando al metodo del ws el parametro que envio es

['Lineas'=>$this->obtener_ArrayLineas($dato)]

Y el parametro del encabezado

Comment: No es necesario poner el `$contador`, sólo podrías poner:

`$ArrayOfLineas['Linea'][] = $detalle;` :)

Comment: Bueno, es cierto, tienes razon :D voy a editarlo. Gracias!